# D3 .exit() not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Any insight is much appreciated. I'm tying myself in knots here as a relative d3 newcomer.

I have a map of the US that I'm placing markers on which display three different sets of data in csv files. I have three radio buttons you can check, and a "show" button which runs render() when clicked. I've tried to set it up such that the data automatically updates with enter, update, and exit, but it's not working. It seems to leave the previous data or, in some sequences, combine or subtract data. I've totally confused myself. I appreciate your help. Here's the code. If there's anything I can add please let me know.

```
var heights = d3.select("#heights");
var lengths = d3.select("#lengths");
var volumes = d3.select("#volumes");
var show = d3.select('#show');
var dataset;



heights.on('click', function(){
  dataset = "./public/assets/data/us_heights_test.csv";
});
lengths.on('click', function(){
  dataset = "./public/assets/data/us_lengths_test.csv";
});
volumes.on('click', function(){
  dataset = "./public/assets/data/us_volumes_test.csv";
});

show.on('click', function(){
  render();
});

var render = function(){

  d3.csv(dataset, function(error, latlon){ 

      latlon.forEach(function(d) {
        d.Lat = +d.Lat;
        d.Long = +d.Long;
      });

    var circles = landmarks.selectAll("circle")
      .data(latlon);

      circles
        .data(latlon)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr({
          'fill': '#F00',
          'r': 3,
          'class': 'dot'
        })
        .each(function(d) {
          var sel = d3.select(this);
          var xy = projection([d.Long, d.Lat]);
            if(typeof xy[0]==='undefined') {
              console.log("undefined");
            } else {
            sel.attr("cx", xy[0]);
            sel.attr("cy", xy[1]);
          }
        })
        .style({
          'opacity': 0.5
        })
        .on("mouseover", details);

     circles
       .exit()
       .remove();
  });
};
```

Comment: It looks like you're calling `.data()` twice.

Comment: I removed the second .data() call and It's still not clearing out the previous set.

Comment: You probably also want a key function that tells D3 how to match data and DOM elements (second argument to `.data()`).

Comment: I added the key function function(d){return d;} If I'm reading this right, that function is assigning a key to every item in the output array that is... itself? I must not understand that correctly. In any case, now when I render I only see a single data point.

Comment: Could you provide a complete example that demonstrates the problem please?

Comment: http://bwstud.github.io/localized_measures/

Comment: Ok, so what should I do to reproduce the bug?

Comment: well, there are three radio buttons at the top left of the view. Pick one, then hit the 'show' button. You should see one red dot appear. This is only happening now that I've added the key function. If I leave the .data() call with just the argument feeding in the dataset all the markers appear.

Comment: Does it work if you use `function(d) { return d.Lat + "-" d.Lon; }` as key function?

Comment: Kind of. It fully rendered the heights and lengths data, but not volumes. I've got a version working now by separating the enter and update selections. The .each function is removed from the enter function, and placed in its own selection. I don't understand why this is working, but it is. Thank you for looking at this tonight. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Right, it sounds like you need to put more information in the key -- this is something that *uniquely* identifies your datum, i.e. if you want to distinguish between different types of markers at the same location you need to put that in there as well.